# How to loop through a checkboxlist and to find what's checked and not checked?

Tags: c#, .net, checkboxlist

I'm trying to loop through items of a checkbox list. If it's checked, I want to set a value. If not, I want to set another value. I was using the below, but it only gives me checked items:

```
foreach (DataRowView myRow in clbIncludes.CheckedItems)
{
    MarkVehicle(myRow);
}
```

Comment: asp316: WebForms or WinForms? (The APIs surrounding their respective CheckBoxList controls are quite different.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < clbIncludes.Items.Count; i++)
  if (clbIncludes.GetItemChecked(i))
    // Do selected stuff
  else
    // Do unselected stuff
```

If the the check is in indeterminate state, this will still return true. You may want to replace

```
if (clbIncludes.GetItemChecked(i))
```

with

```
if (clbIncludes.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
```

if you want to only include actually checked items.

Comment: Using this worked great. How can I get the value/value member of the checked checkbox?

Comment: clbIncludes.GetItemChecked(i) was not a valid method for me, but I simply replaced it with clbIncludes.Items[i].Selected

Answer (score 32):

This will give a list of selected

```
List<ListItem> items =  checkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(n => n.Selected).ToList();
```

This will give a list of the selected boxes' values (change Value for Text if that is wanted):

```
var values =  checkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(n => n.Selected).Select(n => n.Value ).ToList()
```

Comment: I get error for both of them.. with first solution i get error **'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem''** and with second i get error at run time **The name 'values' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 23):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in clbIncludes.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected) { 
        //do some work 
    }
    else { 
        //do something else 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's winform. So, when i try to reference listitem, it's wanting to reference a the web control. i tried using a listviewitem and get the error 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'. 

Thoughts

Comment: bill martin if it's winform then remove your tag that says .net.  I spent some time trying to figure out why your solution didn't work for me (using .net) when I realized the GetItemChecked method only applies to winforms.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to use `CheckedItems`:

```
 foreach (DataRowView objDataRowView in CheckBoxList.CheckedItems)
 {
     // use objDataRowView as you wish                
 }
```

Comment: I didn't find a CheckedItems properties for CheckBoxList.

Answer (score 1):

check it useing loop for each index in `comboxlist.Items[i]`

```
bool CheckedOrUnchecked= comboxlist.CheckedItems.Contains(comboxlist.Items[0]);
```

I think it solve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use the CheckBoxList's GetItemChecked or GetItemCheckState method to find out whether an item is checked or not by its index.