# How to reference dynamically created checkedlistbox items in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to see if a particular item in a checkedlistbox is checked or not.
I assumed referencing the item would be:

```
var checkBox = CheckBoxCheckedListBox1.Items[0];
```

But that returns an object. Casting to a CheckBox throws an exeption.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395454/how-to-loop-thru-a-checkboxlist-and-to-find-whats-checked-and-not-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bool checked = CheckBoxCheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)` here.